# Access MI Band through Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, mi

I am a new bee to the android world, smartwatches, fitness bands. I am basically a.NET web developer. Need possible ways to access MI band and its data through Bluetooth programmatically.

Can anyone please help me with related documentation links and sample application code links.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The MI Band uses Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) and you can start accessing its services using any generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile). You should find out what services the band offers and what kind of data it makes available.

After you found what you are looking for using a generic app you could start developing your own app/program. This part depends on the language you want to use. There are many BLE libraries and tutorials for different platforms available online.

I just found [this](https://github.com/satcar77/miband4) library which allows you to access a Xiaomi MiBand4 from linux.